# Syntax Error installing django-badgify

Tags: python, django, django-apps

When I try to install [django-badgify](https://github.com/ulule/django-badgify), I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/myusername/Developer/hackerspace_online/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/init.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/myusername/Developer/hackerspace_online/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/init.py", line 312, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/myusername/Developer/hackerspace_online/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/init.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/myusername/Developer/hackerspace_online/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/home/myusername/Developer/hackerspace_online/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/home/myusername/Developer/hackerspace_online/lib/python3.4/importlib/init.py", line 109, in import_module
    return bootstrap.gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "", line 2231, in _gcd_import
  File "", line 2214, in _find_and_load
  File "", line 2203, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "", line 1129, in _exec
  File "", line 1448, in exec_module
  File "", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/myusername/Developer/hackerspace_online/lib/python3.4/site-packages/badgify/models/__init.py", line 5, in
    from ..utils import load_class
  File "/home/myusername/Developer/hackerspace_online/lib/python3.4/site-packages/badgify/utils.py", line 56
    except ImportError, e:
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am using Django 1.8 and Python 3.4. Is this a problem I can fix? (If so, what is it!?) or a bug in the django-badgify app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That version of the project is using Python 2 specific syntax, and cannot be used with Python 3. This in spite of the project's [hopeful claims of compatibility](https://github.com/ulule/django-badgify/commit/c80972478d7db0147e4c451495be6eaa1b6e9708).

Fixing it to work on Python 3 is *probably* going to require more effort than just fixing that syntax error. This is something the maintainers will have to undertake.

Lucky for you [recent changes](https://github.com/ulule/django-badgify/commit/b726bf8e712f9ac79bedd60b3c1b35a6fffd8c07) did address those, but the current 0.1.5 does not yet include those fixes. You'll have to check out the GitHub master branch to get those:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/ulule/django-badgify.git
```

I do not know if the project managed to address all Python 3 issues. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: Ok, but if I'm reading the page right, they THINK it is python 3.4 compatible right? at the bottom of the page it lists compatibilities: https://github.com/ulule/django-badgify

Comment: @43Tesseracts: ah, they do claim compatibility. But the code you installed is *not* compatible. I'll take a look.

Comment: @43Tesseracts: the code on GitHub has moved on from the version you are using, at the very least.

Comment: @43Tesseracts: the 0.1.5 release on PyPI does not include the fixes; the project has yet to create a release with the fixes included.